# Testing parameterized AngularJS filter in Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, angularjs-filter

I have a filter that takes arguments:

```
{{'filter input' | filterName:arg1:arg2}}
```

Normally to test a filter I do:

```
it('should work',inject(function($filter){
    expect($filter('filterName')('filter input')).toEqual('whatever');
}));
```

How do I include additional arguments `:arg1:arg2` in the test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was actually kind of obvious:

```
it('should work',inject(function($filter){
    expect($filter('filterName')('filter input', 'arg1', 'arg2)).toEqual('whatever');
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering this myself yesterday. I stumbled on a blog post that showed me. Testing a filter in AngularJS is like testing a function in JavaScript. If you have a filter that looks like this:

```
.filter('SomeFilter', function () {
        return function (arg1, arg2) {
          return arg1 + ' ' + arg2;
        }
}
```

You could test it like this:

```
it('should work', inject(function($filter) {
  var arg1 = 'hello';
  var arg2 = 'world';

  var someFilter = $filter('SomeFilter');
  var result = someFilter(arg1, arg2);
  expect(result).toBe(arg1 + ' ' + arg2);
}));
```

There are other syntax stuff too. I just found the blog post I mentioned about [testing filters in angularjs](http://www.ecofic.com/about/blog/test-filters-in-angularjs)